# how to stretch image without disturbing the aspect ratio of image in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have created a `view pager`, It has a images, that comes from server. 
The resolution of the image is `980X551`.

I need to display this image in half of the screen.

In ViewPage Layout, I set the `widthXheight` of image to `match_parent`.

and in my `MainActivity`, I use weight to define the height of `ViewPager`.

The problem is that, In my `Main Activity` when i increase the height of
image, its start stretching, and i need to show this in half Page., and it 
looked  quite stretch when i set its height to half screen.

Kindly guide me how to stretch image without disturbing the aspect ratio of image in Android

**View Pager Code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"

        >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            />
```

Comment: Can you provide complete layout files? Are you sure image is stretched and not cropped?

Comment: Yes,Its stretched,I am adding the layout code

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Pisasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** for Android

Among a lot of other options, it allows you to load and  resize images.

An example code could be:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(screeWidth/2, screen height/2)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

`centerCrop` option may be fit your situation. 
And `adjustViewBounds` is not needed.

like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```